# Implement hash URL using jQuery in the AJAX calls in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm a beginner in using jQuery along with Spring MVC framework, trying my luck on building a basic utility that might be helpful at work. I've made a bunch of AJAX calls using jQuery in the code.

Now, I want to make use of the back button of the browser and figured I'd need to use an anchor in the URL. Not sure about how to proceed, after a bit of browsing tried `window.location.hash="value"` in the success part of the AJAX call, although the hash was appended in the URL, the back button did not work.
Any tip would be helpful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that whenever you change the hash portion of the URL, the page does not reload or anything. That's the beauty and the curse of the hash... : )

Your solution only has one half of the overall solution: changing the hash value of the current url, so that your link can be shared with others.

In order for the back button to work, you will need to play around with the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).(A [good tutorial is here](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/))

In your case, you will basically have to redo your previous ajax calls to get back the state from the previous page when the "popstate" handler is called. Or you could store the ajax response as you pushState to the history API. But either way, you will have to re-apply your dynamic page building on popstate.

The back button usually asks the server for the previous page's URL. Now in a single page application, you will have to do all that work yourself an rebuild the previous page somehow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.Shall explore on the same lines :)